# How does Set::nest in Cakephp 2 works?

Tags: cakephp, nested, resultset

Due to the lack of proper documentation I have difficulties
to understand "Set::nest" CakePhp function.

I would appreciate if somebody can explain generally
and with my example how to use it properly.

Let's say I have this tree:

```
array(
    (0) => array(
        'Category' => array('name' => 'Cat 1'),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 1'
        ),
        'Day' => array('date' => '2012-01-01')
    ),
    (1) => array(
        'Category' => array('name' => 'Cat 1'),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 1'
        ),
        'Day' => array('date' => '2012-01-02')
    ),
    (2) => array(
        'Category' => array('name' => 'Cat 1'),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 3'
        ),
        'Day' => array('date' => '2012-01-06')
    ),
    (3) => array(
        'Category' => array('name' => 'Cat 2'),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 2'
        ),
        'Day' => array('date' => '2012-01-02')
    ),
)
```

to be transformed to:

```
array(
    'Cat 1' => array(
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 1'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-01'),
            array('date' => '2012-01-02')
        ),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 3'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-06')
        ),
    ),
    'Cat 2' => array(
        'Courses' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 2'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-03')
        )
    ),
)
```

As you can see it's kind of a double nesting because "Category" can have multiple "Course" rows and "Course" can have multiple "Day".

I could just loop through it and do it manually.

So the fist question is: can I transform this with Set::nest at all
and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible. Your array is not valid. You need to change your format to have each category as a nested array `'cat' => array(array('course 1' =>  ...), array('course 2' => ...))`

```
print_r(array(
    'Cat 1' => array(
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 1'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-01'),
            array('date' => '2012-01-02')
        ),
        'Course' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 3'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-06')
        ),
    ),
    'Cat 2' => array(
        'Courses' => array(
            'name' => 'Course 2'
        ),
        'Day' => array(
            array('date' => '2012-01-03')
        )
    ),
));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Cat 1] => Array
        (
            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Course 3
                )

            [Day] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2012-01-06
                        )

                )

        )

    [Cat 2] => Array
        (
            [Courses] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Course 2
                )

            [Day] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2012-01-03
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: So you told me that I need to do what I asked how to do, right?
The question is: "How does Set::nest in Cakephp 2 works?"

Comment: No, I am telling you that the output you require is impossible.